# White space with subfigures using a macro

Tags: spacing, macros, graphics, subfloats

**EDIT**

The answer proposed by egreg doesn't work for me:

[image]

When changing the `outer sep` to `outer sep=-10pt`, instead of shifting the images, just the labels get shifted and the white space persists.

[image]

I guess this indicates the white space is generated somewhere outside the tikzpicture environment.

Any ideas?

**Initial question**

I want to place several subfigures within a figure in multiple rows. Since I don't want the several rows of images being separated by the subcaption of the subfigures, I defined a macro, placing a label on the images with tikz and using the `\phantomsubcaption` command:

```
\newcommand{\customcaption}[4]%
{%
    {%
    \tikz%
        {%
            \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};%
            \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]%
                \draw[white] (0,0) node [font=\footnotesize, anchor=south west] {#3};%
            \end{scope}%
        }%
        \phantomsubcaption\label{#4}%
    }%
}%
% Macro to typeset a label onto a picture and putting a \phantomlabel for reference
% Arguments are: #1 Dimension of the graphic, #2 file path, #3 drawn label, #4 reference label
```

However, the macro produces white space arround the images, which I can't get rid of.

[image]

What do I need to do, to prevent the white space?

Here is a MWE replacing `\includegraphics` by an rectangle drawn with tikz:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[font+=footnotesize, subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
%
\newcommand{\customcaption}[2]%
{%
    {%
    \tikz%
        {%
            \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0, fill=black, shape=rectangle, minimum size=3cm] (image) at (0,0) {};%
            \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]%
                \draw[white] (0,0) node [font=\footnotesize, anchor=south west] {#1};%
            \end{scope}%
        }%
        \phantomsubcaption\label{#2}%
    }%
}%
%
\begin{document}%
%
\begin{figure}%
    \centering
    \customcaption{(a)}{a}%
    \customcaption{(b)}{b}%
    \customcaption{(c)}{c}%
\end{figure}%
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems like word space. But we cannot reproduce these spaces using your MWE. I.e., there is a problem in your inputted files.

Comment: @wipet There are no input files in my MWE and the pictures I am posting are generated with my MWE or the code given by egreg in his answer.

Comment: When I run your MWE then there are 113 another input files. See the log file: book.cls, bk12.clo, tikz.sty, pgf.sty, pgfrcs.sty, pgfutil-common.tex, pgfutil-common-lists.tex, etc, etc. And something similar is at your side in your computer. One of your input file is bad.

Comment: @wipet As already mentioned in my comment under egregs answer, all my LaTex packages are up to date!

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting `outer sep`.

Don't be obsessed by end-of-lines! ;-)

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[font+=footnotesize, subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}

\newcommand{\customcaption}[2]{{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[
    anchor=south west,
    inner sep=0,
    outer sep=-0.2pt,
    fill=black,
    shape=rectangle,
    minimum size=3cm
  ] (image) at (0,0) {};
  \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
    \draw[white] (0,0) node [font=\footnotesize, anchor=south west] {#1};
  \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \phantomsubcaption\label{#2}%
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\customcaption{(a)}{a}%
\customcaption{(b)}{b}%
\customcaption{(c)}{c}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Spaces inside a `tikzpicture` are ignored (but they are necessary for syntactic purposes, of course). So you just need `%` after `\end{tikzpicture}`.

No `%` is necessary after `\begin{figure}` or `\end{figure}`.

[image]

Comment: This is strange. When compiling your code I get exactly the same result as in my question. The white space persists! Looks like there is something different wrong as well. :-/

Comment: @JMP Possibly an issue with outdated software?

Comment: When thinking about your answer twice, you just corrected for half the linewidth of the outer boundary, which was not drawn. When saying `filldraw=black` instead of `fill=black` the whitespace should vanish for you, without using `outer sep=-0.2pt`. But then the question is, why is the white space created for me, but it works for you?

Comment: First thing I did, after you proposed your answer and it didn't worked for me was updating my latex packages. However, the problem persists. So I don't think it's a software issue.

Comment: @JMP If I compile your code, I just get the space due to the border, much less than in your picture.

Comment: What software do you use? Its TeXnicCenter and Miktex here. Just another heretical question: Are your latex packages up to date? Probably there is some bug in some newer package?

Comment: Crosschecked the compilation of your code with another TeX editor (TeXworks). This gives the same output for me, including the unwanted white space...

Comment: @JMP the editor you use is not relevant: check the version of tikz that you are loading (the log file will give the version as the package is loaded)

Comment: @JMP My TeX Live is fully up-to-date.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The log file says: Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151), which means it is up to date.

Comment: @JMP yep same as here (texlive 2016) I have no idea then:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle okay I guess I'll recompile my code on a different machine and see what happens...

Comment: Could be this bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/20/ However, it should be resolved when using the latest version of the `caption` package bundle available on CTAN. So double-check the version of `subcaption.sty` actually used when compiling your document, it should be from `2016-02-20`.